# Balance not equal to inputs

Tags: accounts, xlm

This account has two inputs: 1 and 0.5 XLM. However, the balance does not equate to 1.5 XLM. Why is that?

http://testnet.stellarchain.io/address/GDUUJCQZQJS5FQ2XVU47ZTNXHOWX3WI6L3KLKZBV7OCHBW5SBNLGPZ5K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is a failed transaction executed:
https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GDUUJCQZQJS5FQ2XVU47ZTNXHOWX3WI6L3KLKZBV7OCHBW5SBNLGPZ5K/transactions?include_failed=true

And the fee charged is 100 stroops.